# Doubt in terminologies used in Ganache Interface

Tags: blockchain, ethereumjs, ganache

I am developing a DApp (an e-commerce app) based on Ethereum. I wrote the solidity contract and interact it with a NodeJS server/web3js API. I am running a Ganache Ethereum RPC client locally. The app is running fine. I am making all the contract calls from the default account *(web3.eth.accounts[0])*.

I just have a few questions regarding the terminologies shown in this image of Ganace Interface.

1. What does the **From Address** and **To Contract Address** signifies?
2. What does **Value** mean? Why is it 0?
3. Who paid for the gas when I did a contract call(which resulted in a transaction and then a block) via the web app?
4. Who is the Miner of this Block 5?

[image: Ganache Interface running on my localhost]

Answer (score 3):

First i need to tell you that every action that change the state of the blockchain need to be a transaction. So when you need to call a function that change a value from the blockchain you need to make a transaction to that contract.

1. The From address signifies the address that make the transaction and the to address is the address that receive the transaction.
2. Value is just the value the address from send to the address to. The reason why it is 0 is because you just want the contract address to excute for you something that will change the state of the blockchain (don’t want to send it some ether) so you dont need to send any value unless the function in the contract require some value to execute
3. The gas is pay by the from address, you can check the account section for the address with the same hash as the from address and you will see that its balance is lower than other addresses the reason is because it has to pay the gas.
4. If you are using ganache then ganache is your miner, it will automatic mine for you so you dont need to care much about the mining

Comment: Just to clarify: value is the amount of Ether you send with the transaction. Typically it's 0 unless you excplicitly want to send some Ether with the transaction (the called function has to be also marked as `payable` so it's able to receive those Ethers)